# Error while execing a docker image

Tags: docker, centos7

I am building an centos image CentOS 7.2.1511 from [CentOs 7.2 docker image](https://github.com/CentOS/sig-cloud-instance-images/blob/CentOS-7.2.1511/docker/Dockerfile).

After i run the image with command
`docker run -d --name centos centos`

I execed a new shell with
`docker exec -user root centos`

Inside the new shell i tried installing mysql and start mysql with the command.
`service mysqld start`

The mysqld start command is failing with below message

`Failed to get D-Bus connection: Operation not permitted`.

Any idea what could be the issue here?

Comment: There is no init inside a standard Docker container. Docker containers are designed to run one program but workarounds exists (supervisor for example : https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/multi-service_container/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use this command to start

CMD ["/usr/sbin/init"]